# Structural Analysis Library

Tags: finite-element, c++, solid-mechanics

Can anyone recommend a structural analysis library that satisfies the following requirements:

- C++ API
- Simulate both beam elements and shell (slab) elements
- Both static and dynamic analysis
- Free and/or open-source

We're essentially looking to find a library that can do analysis similar to e.g. [SAP2000](https://www.csiamerica.com/products/sap2000).

However we are looking to incorporate this analysis in our larger software product, so we'd like the library to have an API that we can include and link against (i.e. has header(s) and dll(s)).

I am aware of, at least, [libMesh](https://libmesh.github.io/). Are there other popular libraries I should be considering?